# javascript "with" structure produce undefined vars

Tags: javascript

I have an object called totalRevenue which is responsible for storing stacked revenue of company on a monthly basis.

```
var totalRevenue = {
    jan : 147,
    feb : 290,
    mar : 400
    };
```

Not all month names are present in `totalRevenue` object & they are created dynamically when populating/estimating their respective values. 
In the beginning of every month, we estimate revenue of that month using an algorithm. sth like this:

```
with(totalRevenue){
    mar = mar - feb; // here we calculate pure mar revenue
    feb = feb - jan; // here we calculate pure feb revenue
    apr = mar - feb; // this is part one of the algo.       
}
```

(I'm using `with` construct to avoid repetition.)
Now I'm using `totalRevenue.apr` for the rest of algo computations. But after some challenge, I got that `totalRevenue.apr = undefined` !!
Does anyone know why?! As I expected it to have a value equal to `mar - feb`.

Comment: [`with` is not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)

Comment: Also, you can't calculate the values out of sequence. Once you fix the *with* issue, you'll get the wrong value for *apr*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `apr` isn't a property of `totalRevenue` then it's not brought into scope by `with` and your code will create a new global named `apr`. There would be no way for the interpreter to know if a given name refers to a global or was intended to refer to a heretofore undefined property of the nearest `with` block so the assumption is it's a global. You can either ensure that `totalRevenue` has a property for every month or avoid using the with statement entirely. Using `with` is discouraged [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) has this to say:

> Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Contra" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.